# Не выводит результат, php7

Tags: php

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Name: </label> <input type="text" name="fname"><?php echo "$fnameErr";?><br><br>
    <label>Surname: </label><input type="text" name="lname"><?php echo $lnameErr; ?><br><br>
    <label>Age:</label><input type="text" name="age" ><?php echo  $ageErr;?><br><br>
    <label>E-mail:</label><input type="text"><?php echo $emailErr;?><br><br>
    <label>Gander: </label><br><br>
    <label>Male</label><input type="radio" name="gander" value="Male">
    <label>Female</label><input type="radio" name="gander" value="Female"><?php echo $ganderErr;?>
    <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
<?php
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $ageErr = $emailErr =  $genderErr = "";
$fname = $lname = $age = $email =  $gender = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "Вы не ввели имя";
    } else {
        $fname = $_POST["fname"] ;
    }
    if (empty($_POST["$lname"])) {
        $lnameErr = "Вы не ввели фамилию";
    } else {
        echo $lname = $_POST["$lname"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["$age"])) {
        $ageErr = "Вы не ввели возраст";
    } else {
        echo $age = $_POST["$age"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["$email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Вы не ввели эмаил";
    } else {
        echo $email = $_POST["$email"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["$gander"])) {
        $ganderErr = "Вы не ввели пол";
    } else {
        echo $gander = $_POST["$gander"];
    }
}
echo "<p>$fname</p> ";
echo "<p>$lname</p>";
echo "<p>$age</p>";
echo "<p>$email</p>";
echo "<p>$gander</p>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В чем проблема, уже сижу полчаса и не могу понять в чем я допустил ошибку.

Comment: Какой результат и куда не выводит? Ошибки какие?

Comment: Ввожу все значения, но выводит только первое

Comment: если не ввожу никакие то даже ошибки не показывает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в коде много странного.

1. Для начала уберите все символы `$` из проверок типа `if (empty($_POST["$age"])) {`. Корректно у вас обрабатывается только `if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {`
2. Вот в этих конструкциях вы чего добиться хотели? `echo $gander = $_POST["$gander"];` (кстати тут тоже надо заменить на `$_POST["gander"]`). Ну и правильно все же писать `gender`, а не `gander`. `gander` переводится как `глупец`, а мне кажется, что вы все же спрашиваете про пол.
3. Сообщения об ошибках у вас не появляются потому, что вы их пытаетесь выводить раньше, чем определили. У вас сначала идет, например `<?php echo $lnameErr; ?>`, но сама переменная `$lnameErr` задается гораздо ниже, в строке `$lnameErr = "Вы не ввели фамилию";`

по факту, у вас на момент распечатывания значения переменных они все, кроме `$fname` равны пустым строкам

Comment: все эти проблемы легко можно было отследить, включив [отображение всех ошибок и предупреждений](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php), добавив вверху `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: спасибо вы мне очень помогли